# Can't install ubuntu onto brand new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I recently replaced the hard drive of my Samsung n102 netbook with a brand new hard drive. I can't get the computer to read the ubuntu 12.10 install disc at all. It says "OS not found" despite me having changed the BIOS boot order to read the CD/DVD reader I've connected by USB first. What should I do do you think? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this in the past and found that it occurred when I burned the CD at a high speed (say 24x on a 24x drive).  By reducing the burn speed to say 4x I was able to get it to boot and read correctly (in my situation it started to boot but failed quickly with read errors).

Comment: I would tend to agree, if the CD/DVD is defective it will likely be missed entirely, so that it will then try the next in the boot order and find the hard drive but no OS on it.  Maybe try the disk in another computer and see if it will boot, if not then is most certainly a bad disk.  Also, make sure it is looking for the CD drive and not a USB key(could be an easy mistake depending on how the selection was worded, one computer I had listed CD, internal or USB and then a separate selection for the USB key)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I solved it by using a different program to create the CD. I'm assuming you used the default 'Startup Disk Creator' that came preinstalled. I would recommend that you try using 'Unetbootin' to create your disc, and see if it works.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

EDIT: I forgot that Unetbootin was only for creating bootable USB's. I'll leave this information here in case you wanna go that route, but Duncan's answer is likely correct if you want to stick with a CD.